# Optimisation: Show Formula is True

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

If postal regulations state that for a cylindrical parcel the sum of the length and circumference must not exceed 3m, a) show that for a cylindrical parcel whose sum of the length and circumference is 3m the volume V of the cylinder is given by $V=\frac{3C^2-C^3}{4\pi}m^3$, where C is the circumference; b) hence, find the dimensions of the cylindrical parcel which has maximum volume.

For reference, optimisation problems, in general, are not my problem. It's this specific question, and this specific formula (part a) that I can't seem to parse :(

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V=\pi r^2 h$$
$$C=2\pi r \quad r=\frac{C}{2\pi} \to V=\pi \left(\frac{C}{2\pi}\right)^2 h=\frac{C^2}{4\pi} h$$
$$C+h=3 \quad h=3-C \to V=\frac{C^2}{4\pi} (3-C)=\frac{3C^2-C^3}{4\pi}$$

Answer (score 0):

I will work in radius instead of circumference because it is the typical convention, so for part (a).

We need two equations.
The symbols I will use is V = volume, r = radius, h = height/length.

1. For the volume of the cylinder:
   $V = \pi r^2 h$
2. For the relationship between the circumference and height:
   $h = 3-2\pi r$

Then we can substitute equation 2 into equation 1, and obtain equation 3.

$V = \pi r^2 (3-2 \pi r)$

This is your answer for part (a), just substitute the equation $ 2 \pi r = C$.

Meanwhile for part (b), using equation 3

$V = 3 \pi r^2 - 2\pi^2 r^3$

Differentiate it,

$\frac{dV}{dr} = 6\pi r - 6\pi ^2r^2$

And to find the point of maximum volume, the gradient is $0$, $\frac{dV}{dr} = 0$

$6\pi r - 6\pi ^2r^2 = 0$

$r-\pi r^2 = 0$

$r(1-\pi r) = 0$

So,

$r = 0$ or $ 1-\pi r = 0$

$r = 0 $ corresponds to the minimum volume. (can find the second order derivative to prove this)

$r = \frac{1}{\pi}$ corresponds to maximum volume.

So this is your solution, and to find C or h, simply substitute r into,

$ C = 2 \pi r$ and $h = 3-2\pi r$

hope this helps :)